Closed Loop Pulse Propulsion - The basic newtonian mechanics are clear. Why does this violate the LoCEM?
Here's the conundrum.
Before answering all hateful and calling me stupid for not knowing things... this is an honest and real question... well, it's a set of questions and on every other site I have asked these questions I have been mocked and ridiculed for being too stupid for words.  Please don't reply if you don't know.  Please.  I know I'm stupid and don't have a proper education.  Since you do... please have at least a little decorum in your answer.  Understand, I am a normal human being with limited intellect... calling me stupid and being hateful is pointless.
I also understand that using AI as a source isn't valid but I am using it to clean up my logic in this question only so please, before reading this nonsense, as I don't have the physics language to explain it right... this is a chat that just fixes my questions so you can figure out what I'm really asking.  That's all... it's not intended to be insulting... just helpful.  I still need professional eyes on this...
https://chatgpt.com/share/6707c4de-de90-800b-a9de-0ad94c8adad0

The Laws of the Conservation of energy and the Conservation of momentum are built on the laws that govern basic Newtonian Physics.  As I understand it, to break the laws of the Conservation of Energy and the Conservation of Momentum, which I've abbreviated to LoCEM to make life easier. But to Break the LoCEM, you must break one of the Newtonian laws... the foundational laws
It was my understanding that in order to prove a violation of the LoCEM, you could site the basic Newtonian law that was in violation.
For instance.  Is it true that if you spin something in space, you can never create linear momentum.  If a system is designed to create angular momentum, it can never induce linear momentum unless there were terrible inefficiencies in the design?
For instance.  Say I HillBilly McGyvered a bucket to a spinning arm and it was only 50% efficient.  Meaning half the energy went into angular momentum if I shoot a bowling ball into the bucket and the other half just burned up in heat and sound.
The bucket would spin around and just grind to a squeaky halt, right? It wouldn't drive your spacecraft forward.  You can't spin anything to make something move in space.  That's a fact.  You have to have Thrust no?  Isn't that torque... no matter how shitty it's designed?
So First Question.  If a device is designed to spin something, can it drive linear momentum?
If the answer is the squeaky grinding motion might drive some linear momentum, maybe, I'm ok with that.  A tiny little bit is ok and that makes sense but most would just try to turn that something, no?
Now, that is not to say you can't spin something and then drive linear motion.
Think of the baseball player, he rotates the bat in a closed system and then strikes the ball, sending it moving away at some vector and speed away from the batter... if he doesn't wiff.  LOL.  But the rotational motion, the angular momentum drove the linear direction... or added linear momentum to the ball.   Obviously at the cost of the speed of the bat, no?  I mean the energy had to come from somewhere... isn't that the LoCEM?
So if a system is designed to create linear momentum, it can't create angular momentum.  (Well, if we're going to nitpick, it's almost impossible not to create both... that's inefficiencies for you. You try to drive something linearly and there's just a little spin and vice versa but for the most part, the idea should hold true, No? Especially on Earth where friction just makes everything really tough to think about but just focus on space...
if you spin it, it spins... if you thrust it, it moves straight... fair?)
So, for any device to violate the LoCEM.  You have to show which Newtonian Physics law it violates.  Correct?
So let's try something else.  You've all read Huck Finn.  Let's say I have a Huck Finn raft on a tranquil lake and I have a really heavy medicine ball and some launcher of some sort.  Figure a bra tie between two poles... anything...
So.  If I walk across the raft, the raft's inertia is heavy enough that even if I have the ball in hand, the raft really doesn't move.  If I fire the ball out of the launcher though, the raft moves a lot.  Is that ok?
So let's figure this out... Chicken and Egg.
I shoot the ball out of the launcher.  And let's amp that up.  Let's make it a really strong spring loaded launcher that can fire that heavy mass strong enough to move the raft at a velocity of 10 m/s and the raft is 10m long and well, there's a sticky wall that catches the ball.  So the ball is shot, it flies for 2 seconds so the raft is really 20m long and both the raft and the ball stop.
Phew.  Sorry, I didn't catch the distance at first.
So the ball is now 20m away and not 10m.
The mass of the raft is such that if I walk across the platform, no noticeable movement in the raft.  Also, it's substantial enough that if I pick up the ball and carry it back, there's still no noticeable movement in the raft.  I mean, in space, there would be but on Earth, I think they call it water shear... but the water would hold you in place.
It's only when I shoot that ball out of that strong spring launcher am I able to shift the center of mass of the whole system.
Bear with me.
So the ball is in the launcher.  The Center of mass is set.
You Fire the ball.  The Raft moves one way and the ball the other.  Both of their center of masses are changing to balance the center of mass of the whole system.  It has to... that's LoCEM.
Once the ball is stopped against the platform, both the ball and the raft are now stopped in the water.  The center of mass of the ball and platform has changed but as a system.  No change.
Your mass is not enough to affect the inertia of the platform, not on water on Earth or really even in Space.  Your combined mass, no matter how hard you run will affect the inertia of the raft much.  It does if you get crazy but not much.  It's only if you put the medicine ball into the launcher and fire it into the back wall can you force the center of mass of the platform to change as you are forcing the center of mass of the medicine ball to change.  No?
Or am I wrong?
So if you're combined mass of you and the ball can not overcome the inertia of the platform/raft, how does the raft shift back?  That's the first Question and I do understand that's and easy one that I should just get... but I don't so if you can handle that... that would be great.
Question 1.  Can you spin something to make it move it's X,Y,Z position in space or even on Water?
Question 2: Can you reset the system if you can't overcome the inertia of the system by adding an overwhelming amount of momentum in one direction and not enough momentum in the other?
Question 3
Ok
So remember the bucket and the bowling ball?
So I shoot the bucket into t... no I shoot the bowling ball into the bucket.  The Bucket is on an arm that is on a really nice pivot point.  Let's say the arm is on some crazy magnetic nearly frictionless bearing thing...  I shoot the bowling ball into the bucket and the bucket starts spinning like crazy no?
Let's shoot a cannonball at it... LOL.
Now.  Wait... we have a problem now don't we?
Yikes!
So... Let's figure this out.  Can you shoot a cannonball in space?
Yes.  I guess but wouldn't a railgun or spring gun be better?
So I take a railgun and fire the Giant Cannonball.  Let's say it's 10 kg.
Let's say I can fire that at 100 m/s and the platform/raft/spaceship is 1000 kg.
Now, I don't want to argue about math so can we just agree it might be possible that that concoction could get the raft going 1 m/s?  I think that's OK.  I know it's more than that but I don't care and we don't need to worry about that as there is some configuration of momentum that can get the raft moving at 1 m/s so I'm going to just say... the platform is now moving at 1 m/s and the ball is moving at some speed.  Is that ok?
Awesome.  So.  If I fire the ball and the ball makes the platform move a 1 m/s before landing in the bucket, the bucket will catch the ball and start spinning around.  Let's say there's goo in the bucket to catch the ball.
So you shoot the ball and the bucket catches it.
Think about that crazy shit on water.  What does the spinning heavy bucket do?
So if I have a bowling ball in a bucket attached to an arm with a motor and I fire up the motor, doesn't the raft just spin around?  If I hit the bucket with the ball and spin the bucket and ball around, doesn't the bucket and ball just spin the raft around?  Is there an Echo in here... LOL.  Sorry, joke.  But really, isn't that the same thing, especially if I spun the bucket up before hand and caught the ball while it was already spinning...
Think about that... would spinning the bucket up make the raft move in water or space?
No.
So why would adding mass to the spinning wheel create linear momentum when the device is already making angular momentum?
Question 3.  Can a device that is designed to create angular momentum, create linear momentum?
I am so sorry, I forgot we asked and answered that.
Let's start over, real fast.
So, I fire a projectile out of a launcher.  That causes a recoil in the raft.  The dynamic separate for some distance and the system now converts to a system that can only create angular momentum.  The projectile is caught by some sort of tether system... call it magic, or just a magnet... the projectile is spun around...
What happens... what is happening to the raft?  Is the linear motion affected?  Is the raft just turning?
If I never stop the projectile from spinning, what stops the raft?
Question 4.  If I accelerate a platform linearly with a projectile and then redirect that projectile into a system design to only create angular momentum, is there any linear momentum created?  (Obviously minus minor inefficiencies which have not ever been known to produce any sort of useable propulsion in space, to our current knowledge anyway)
Question 5:  While that projectile is spinning, what is happening to the platform?  The center of mass of the platform was changed linearly when the projectile was fired.  The center of mass of the platform continued to change until the projectile struck the tether, now the center of mass of the system is rotating around that axis... but the linear momentum of the platform wasn't affected as the energy came from the slug, so what stops the platform if the reverse momentum to stop the platform is still in the spinning slug?
IF the spinning of the does stop the platform, what if I release the slug in another direction other than the opposite direction of the initial recoil?
I am so confused?
Let's start over.
I have a large platform.  It's 500m long.
I have two launchers that can accelerate 100 kg to 100 m/s.
I'm in space so if they're fired in a direction, they stay in that direction until they hit something.  So I fire and the platform moves at 1 m/s.  Don't worry about the mass of the platform, you can figure it out from the 1 m/s  but it don't matter.
So if I fire and the balls hit the back wall.  The raft stops.  The momentum cancels out.  That's cool.  I get it.
If I fire though and I catch that ball in the tether... what happens?   If the momentum can't cancel out, how do you stop that raft?
Question 6.  How does the raft stop as long as the ball is spinning in the tether?
I feel as though I'm making this harder than it has to be.  What am I asking?
Let's start one last time.
If a platform experiences a linear thrust and the projectile that thrusts the platform moves away for a bit...
Then it's caught in some sort of merry go round, tether system, thingamagig... and spun around...
How does the platform stop?
Then... if it does... when the slug is released in some direction, what happens to that momentum?
And if you add momentum to that slug while it's spinning, what happens... can you spin it up faster and then release it?
So what comes first?
The chicken or the egg?
I say... the egg...
So I have prepared my ideas of what I think happens.  While I have been mercilessly ridiculed for my lack of education and intellect, not one physicist has been able to show me how my ideas violate the Newtonian Laws that govern the laws of the Conservation of Energy and Conservation of Momentum.  Of course, everyone here is going to knee jerk that answer but not one will have any proof of the violation... you'll just 'feel' it's wrong and call me an asshole.  I get it. This is physics, that's how it's done.
This is my primary point of reference for all the information on Closed Loop Pulse Propulsion.  There are working models, VPython Scripts, Links to full Proofs the this does not violate the LoCEM and even stories and rap songs to make it fun.
https://closedlooppulsepropulsion.com/
I understand that to argue physics, you don't actually have to have any real proof or math so I understand this idea is going nowhere on this site as well... All I ask is that you read all the insults thrown at me and find something original.  That's it.  OR..  OR... some real proof this doesn't work and while your opinion works in the real of physics, this is turning into math and well your opinion isn't gonna cut it.  I have math... if all you have is opinion... you lose.  Be a winner today and beat my physics.

Well the first thing you could do is really distill your question down, it's going to attract far less attention because it's so lengthy, almost no one is going to take the time to read through this.

I’m sorry that you’ve received ridicule (ridicule helps nobody learn and just makes people feel bad). It is, however, a fundametal law that you can’t ever get impulse (momentum change) into a closed system. Newton’s laws dictate this. For example, “there’s always an equal and opposite reaction” essentially means “the total force on any system ever is zero.” Force is the change of momentum with time, and saying that the net force is zero means that the net change in momentum over time is also zero, no matter what you try. It would be useful to try and cite the math you have, because then we could actually understand what you’re trying to do on a deeper level and point out where you’re wrong.
(You are wrong, if you think you’ve found inertialess propulsion without a complete warp drive. I thought I had once, too, when I was much younger, but I was in error, as you may be now.)
Momentum is conserved because of Noether’s theorem, which states that if there’s a continuous symmetry (i.e., some arbitrary thing I can do to the system to change it into a different system without changing its mechanical properties at all), then there is an associated conserved quantity that is invariant with time, that is for every symmetry there’s something that has to be conserved between transformations.
“Well, what if Noether’s theorem doesn’t hold?” Noether’s theorem also conserves angular momentum, energy, charge, mass, etc. etc. etc. and since all of these things have always been seen to be conserved in physics, we assume Noether’s theorem is true. If you reject momentum conservation, you also reject energy conservation, angular momentum conservation, charge conservation, mass conservation, and everything else that all modern physics relies upon. For the record: the device you’re reading this post on would not work if not for physics, so take that as evidence.
“Then what’s wrong with my physics?” You’re not considering the momenta of the entire system.

Take your last example:

If a platform experiences a linear thrust and the projectile that thrusts the platform moves away for a bit... Then it's caught in some sort of merry go round, tether system, thingamagig... and spun around... How does the platform stop? Then... if it does... when the slug is released in some direction, what happens to that momentum? And if you add momentum to that slug while it's spinning, what happens... can you spin it up faster and then release it?

It’s hard to tell exactly what’s being suggested here. I’m going to interpret the first part as

If a platform ejects an object which is then caught by another thing (be it another platform, a tether system, etc) and then spun around, what happens to the platform? Does it stop?

No, it doesn’t (in a frictionless vacuum). When the first platform ejected the object, it produced impulse, which accelerated it. It will keep moving forward in that reference frame until another force acts on it.
The whatever that catches the object after ejection gains its linear momentum. It would be like a ice skater catching a thrown baseball: they would start to move backwards slightly. They can allow themselves to spin around once they catch it, but linear momentum is always conserved.
Could the object be somehow given back to the first platform (I’ll call it the rocket from now on since this is clearly geared towards a system of inertialess propulsion)? No. If the catcher throws the ball back, the it will have given itself impulse and will accelerate away much faster from the rocket (not convenient). The catcher could just move over to the rocket and gently set the ejected object back in the “fuel” tank, but the catcher and rocket are currently moving away from each other, and getting close enough would require that the catcher is moving towards the rocket. Doing so would require a reaction engine, which would be better placed on the rocket anyway.
Let’s take another of your examples:

I have a large platform. It's 500m long. I have two launchers that can accelerate 100 kg to 100 m/s. I'm in space so if they're fired in a direction, they stay in that direction until they hit something. So I fire and the platform moves at 1 m/s. Don't worry about the mass of the platform, you can figure it out from the 1 m/s but it don't matter. So if I fire and the balls hit the back wall. The raft stops. The momentum cancels out. That's cool. I get it. If I fire though and I catch that ball in the tether... what happens? If the momentum can't cancel out, how do you stop that raft?

More simply,

I have a big rocket in space and a heavy mass I can eject down a long tunnel running the length of the rocket. If I throw the object down the rocket and do nothing, it hits the back wall and impulse is zero. What if I catch it with a tether and try and throw it in a different direction?

Here’s the key question: is the tether attached to the rocket?
One of two things will happen:

the tether will gain the object’s linear momentum and fly off away from the rocket, or
the rocket, having caught the object indirectly through the tether, will gain zero impulse.

Because the tether is attached to the rocket, if you put an impulse on the tether (while it’s in tension), it’s the same as putting an impulse on the rocket too, because that’s precisely what the rocket is: the rocket is a rocket with a tether; you can’t consider the objects separately.
Try and toss the object forward to reuse it, and you’ll find that doing so results in no impulse forward. Say you have the tether catch the object and throw it forward at the same speed you threw it backward. Then, how is the impulse gained by throwing it back different from the impulse gained by throwing it forward, except in direction? No matter what you do, those impulses will always cancel.
If the tether isn’t connected to the rocket, it will start spinning around its center of mass upon catching the object. This is probably not desirable, but if it isn’t attached to the rocket, it’ll also start flying away at speed, making the system useless.

The bottom line is, inertialess propulsion is not really possible. If you can change spacetime itself, you can make it so that symmetries don’t hold in a certain area and then Noether’s theorem is off your back. But manipulating spacetime and gravity requires enormous negative energy, which is hard to obtain for various reasons.
If you think you’ve found an inertialess propulsion system, great! Do some math and see if it holds up in theory. You say that physics always ends up becoming just math, but that’s the thing, physics is math. Physics is a set of mathematical models that match what we observe in the real world very closely. If you don’t do the math, you aren’t doing physics.
It’s one of the first things you learn in any introductory physics course that momentum is conserved. All three of Newton’s laws depend on it, and more-advanced physics dictates it as well.


All I ask is that you read all the insults thrown at me and find something original. That's it. OR.. OR... some real proof this doesn't work and while your opinion works in the real of physics, this is turning into math and well your opinion isn't gonna cut it. I have math... if all you have is opinion... you lose.

I’ve tried not to be insulting here, since it’s my genuine belief that insults do no good especially in the sciences. And I’m certain - certain - that given a specific diagram of your device and the math you have for it, I could find a fatal flaw. But you don’t specify that here, so I can’t give “real proof”. If you have a working model, my question is have you tested it in space, or at least suspended in a vacuum chamber? Many people have thought they discovered inertialess propulsion, only to find that they were using air/the ground/the table underneath the test apparatus/the Earth’s magnetic field as reaction mass, and were the device to be used in space, nothing would happen.

Lastly, one recommendation: don’t get angry at the physics community. Some of us do ridicule, not because we’re necessarily just like that but because a lot (a lot) of people come to us saying they’re being repressed and have discovered free energy and in fact did zero math and their device doesn’t work at all. It can be frustrating and sometimes when we see this kind of stuff it’s hard to take it seriously.
It’s not good of anybody to insult you, but we are the people you’re currently asking for help! If you come in with an open mindset and respect for those who have spent their lives learning about physics, you will likely learn from them! If you don’t, and call them horrible people who do nothing but make fun, they’re just going to close your posts and ignore your calls. In the former circumstance, there’s a learning interaction that gets you out of the situation better than when you came in; in the latter circumstance, you’re mad and will keep getting more mad because people keep closing your posts on claims of inertialess propulsion, and we’re frustrated because we have to keep closing them all.

You have not been insulting and I love you answers!!!  I will prepare a retort as I think you have misunderstood a few things... I sort of did that on purpose as I needed to dissect the mechanics to force this sort of conversation right here.  Thank you for your wonderful response and I will work to show you the math behind this idea.  I swear it's there and if you could please look at the proof in the AI chat, we can build from there.  I will put that into the my response but this is just a wonderful thank you for your answer!  I absolutely appreciate it and look forward to changing your mind

I don’t think you have the reputation yet to post in chat but good luck. I would recommend learning the basic MathJax syntax as well if you’re going to post math equations, it makes them look much better.
